# AndroidAnnotations error in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-annotations

I have been using AndriodAnnotations with Eclipse (ADT) without any issue. Recently, I decided to explore Android Studio. Using Android Studio with AndroidAnnotations has a few issues when I build the app. Below is the error:

[image]

I can run the app without any issues when it is showing three errors.

Below is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.2+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.restaurantmenu"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

apt {
    arguments {
        androidManifestFile variant.processResources.manifestFile
        resourcePackageName "com.test.restaurantmenu"
    }
}

dependencies {
    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:3.0+"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:3.0+"
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.3'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

I've enabled the annotation processors as follow:

[image]

Is there any steps I missed or wrong in my setup?

Comment: Quick thought - there are two gradle files in Android projects - project file and module file. What you have posted is a module file, but I think that the 

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.2+'
    }
}

should be present in the project-level gradle file. (Well, most of it is already there, just try to add there the classpath line :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed "Android SDK Tools 23.0.2" and all the errors were solved.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you're using kotlin and you're getting an error showing

> error: annotations are not supported in -source 1.3 (use -source 5 or
> higher to enable annotations)

There is a workaround for it

1. Open Project Structure (File -> Project Structure). Select the module.
2. Change the **source compatibility** and **Target compatibility** from  `kotlin 1.3`

   to `jdk 1.8`